# Transfer data between more than two Android devices within a wifi network

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am developing an application. I have to develop client-server app in Android. Server device and Client devices(more than 2 devices) are also in the same WiFi network.

I want to send an Image from server to all the client in the same network. How can I achieve this in Android. From WiFi package in android I don't have found data transfer between devices with in the WiFi network.

Can I have any sample code snippets to Multicast Image within the same wifi network in android?
If any body shares code it is very helpfull in my app.:(

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to discover all other clients in the network. This could be done via [Broadcast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html) netowrk messages.

You app would send a broadcast message on startup and listen for others. When an broadcast comes in, you know the IP of the other client.

Then you can use plain TCP connections or even HTTP to communicate.